# Flatten LaTeX file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, latex

I would like to make a simple PowerShell script that:

1. Takes an input .tex file
2. replaces occurrences of `\input{my_folder/my_file}` with the file content itself
3. outputs a new file

My first step is to match the different file names so as to import them, although the following code outputs not only the file names but also `\include{file1}`, `\include{file2}`, etc.

```
$ms = Get-Content ms.tex -Raw
$environment = "input"

$inputs = $ms | Select-String "\\(?:input|include)\{([^}]+)\}" -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches}

Write-Host $inputs
```

I thought using the parenthesis would create a matched group but this fails, can you to me explain why and what is the proper way of just getting the filenames instead of the full match?

On regex101 this regexp `\\(?:input|include)\{([^}]+)\}` seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Positive lookbehind and positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
@'
Some line
\input{my_folder/my_file}
Other line
'@ | Select-String '(?<=\\input{)[^}]+(?=})' -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches}
```

**Result**

```
Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 18
Length   : 17
Value    : my_folder/my_file
```